# how to send pdf as a file as form-data to server

Tags: javascript, html, html2pdf

I have little knowledge on promises ,

What i have been doing is to convert html to pdf , thankfully **html2pdf** works great ,

Now where I was stuck is getting the pdf as a file and post to server with **form-data**

I have somehow found to get pdf encoded string from [here](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues/181#issuecomment-453028321)

But it is a promise and i have a function as :

```
genPDF:function(){
        var element = document.getElementById('canvasId');    
        var opt = {
            filename: 'nobutton.pdf',
            image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
            // html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
        };

        html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).toPdf().output('datauristring').then(function (res) {
            var blobString = res;
            console.log(blobString);
          });
    }
```

But here it doesn't log at first time , but then the function is called again and then logs , why is that ?? could i get it for the first time the function called ?

Can some one help me how to get the pdf from **html2pdf** as a file so that can append it to **form-data** , any help is really appreciated , Thanks :)

Comment: When you say the function is called again - do you mean the genPDF function ?  The function you pass to .then() will not get called until after genPDF returns, so there will be (I imagine) some delay between calling genPDF and the promise being resolved and .then being called with your function.

Comment: yes there is a delay , i just learnt how it works , but im stuck in convertting pdf string to file object :( any guiding links please

Comment: You could try something like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File - do you need to save the file locally or is it to send to a server ?  If the latter just use an HTTP Post.

Comment: thanks for link @Woody ... one more Q iydm : `html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).toPdf().output('datauristring')` i understood this is a promise , and .then gives me the pdf string , but can this be done (get pdf string) with out a promise ? [ link here to this pdf string  ](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues/181#issuecomment-453028321)

Comment: no - it looks like the API is that the output function returns a promise.  If you find this syntax too verbose, maybe async/await might help you out ?

Comment: yes @Woody , may i know how would the async/await would be for the same ?

Comment: I'll add it as the answer @Sophie - can't fit in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

@Sophie - here is the asnyc version as discussed in the comments.

```
 async genPDF() {
    var element = document.getElementById('canvasId');    
    var opt = {
        filename: 'nobutton.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
        // html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
    };

    let blobString = await html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).toPdf().output('datauristring');
    console.log(blobString);
     
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Woody ... I would try it and let you know :)